# Whom or "of whom"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, whom, who

In the sentence "So, who exactly is Darren; the character who/whom/of whom the film is centred around."

Should it be who/whom or of whom?

Comment: This could be defined as, Darren (former to T.v) is now a Grove tender(r)

Comment: *The film is centered around of Darren?*  I don't think that works.  So *of whom* is ruled out.

Comment: It should be none of the above: _the character the film is centered around_. In a nonrestrictive relative clause, no relative pronoun is necessary, unless it is the subject. Since it's the object of a preposition, it's dispensable. Just strand the preposition _around_ at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In ordinary English, "the character the film is centred around" (thanks for the notice, John Lawler); or for greater clarity, "the character who the film is centred around".

For people who still use 'whom', "the character whom the film is centred around".

In very formal, stilted, English: "the character around whom the film is centred".